# Rename all file name using command in linux?

Tags: linux, unix, command, rename

I want to rename all files with add some word example I have file name test I want to append linux using command I find one command that is rename but that not work properly. So give me idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```
    rename  -v 's/(.*)/\1doc/' *
```

Comment: I don't want extension I need append one word into all files